# Close dropdown menu on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

I am currently working on a project using `Ant Design` and on one page I have a dropdown Menu. When you click on the menu it opens the dropdown but if you scroll down the menu still keeps open. I wish to implement that when the user is scrolling down the menu closes.

I tried to implement a `handleScroll()` function in order to use is with the provided prop `onVisibleChange`. However I am not sure what I should add in the function to get it work.

```
handleScroll = (e) => {
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
console.log('scrolling');
 })
}

<Dropdown onVisibleChange={visible => this.handleScroll( 
console.log(visible)) } trigger={['click']} overlay={
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item key="1"
      onClick={() => this.scrollTo(this.whyRef)}>
      <Icon icon={u1F427} /> <strong>WHY</strong>
      </Menu.Item>
     </Menu>
   }>
 <Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the event listener in the constructor and handle the visibility state of the dropdown yourself. Try something like this:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.closeMenu);
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  };

  closeMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          overlay={menu}
          onVisibleChange={this.toggleMenu}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          trigger={["click"]}
        >
          <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
            Click me <Icon type="down" />
          </a>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2ovjzwqz9y

Comment: Thank you so much this is working beautifully !! Adding the event listener in the constructor changed everything. I will remember that. Thanks so much, I was struggling with that for some time now.

Comment: What if you have a div such as a modal with fixed height( < window) and overflow-y:scroll, then how to listen to scroll on modal because window is on still ?

Comment: @SaheelSapovadia You can handle it the same way if you select the scroll container and attach the event listener to that element. Or, since you would be rendering the div in react, you can just pass an onScroll handler to that element.